# What exactly has happened in WarMetal Tyrant's storyline?

Tags: war-metal-tyrant

I've recently begun playing this game, and I'm curious as to what the storyline is actually about.

Is there actually a backstory?  Some players tell me it's based off of some other game or something, and I'm not sure exactly what exactly happens.

Simply put, why are all the factions there?  Why do the Imperial exist where they are, what planet are they on, etc.

If you can, post your answers in a spoilers tag.  Thanks!

Comment: ...You're asking about the storyline, but you don't want to be spoiled.  The two are irreconcilable.

Comment: I didn't say I wanted it not spoiled.  I just asked people to put spoiler tags SO that others who read the answer don't get spoilers either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**STANDARD CAMPAIGN**

> War Metal: Tyrant takes place on the planet Acheron, where there is currently a war going on between the Empire and the Raiders. You are an Imperial commander following Lord Halcyon, the military leader of the Imperials. The game starts out with you defending the Spire, a base in Ashrock, from the invading Raiders led by Typhon Vex. After driving him off you pursue him, and are assisted by Katana, who acts as your aide. However, things are complicated when the Bloodthirsty begin to attack, which has not happened for years.
>  Lord Halcyon reveals that Typhon is apparently attempting to get his hands on the Prometheus, an extremely powerful artifact that provides energy to half of Acheron. You then catch up to Typhon, but he tells you that you are too late to stop him from getting the Prometheus, and also implies that the Empire is responsible for creating the Bloodthirsty.
>  Typhon escapes to the Wasteland in the west, but you are unable to pursue him immediately, since you are attacked by more Bloodthirsty which have overrun the Swamps of Andar. Lord Halcyon orders you to pursue Typhon immediately, but Katana refuses to abandon people who are in need of help, and decides to head to the Swamps to search for survivors. Therefore, Lord Halcyon heads to the Wasteland while you and Katana strike at the Bloodthirsty.
>  In the Swamps of Andar, you discover survivors led by commander Octane. He tells you that things have become even more complicated as the Xeno faction known as the Enclave have begun to invade the area as well. He then heads west to join up with Lord Halcyon and warn him of the new development. You and Katana head toward the main Bloodthirsty nest, which for some reason, was formerly an Imperial base. Your forces then destroy the Brood Mother at the nest. With the Brood Mother dead, the Bloodthirsty infestation should presumably dissolve with time. With that done, you finally head west towards Lord Halcyon’s forces.

**ENCLAVE CAMPAIGN**

> You arrive in the Red Sands desert, where you again meet Octane. He fills you in on the situation: things are now a total clusterfuck, with the Imperials, Raiders and the Enclave all fighting each other. Your primary mission then becomes to figure out the reason for the Xeno invasion, so you head toward a communications relay under Raider control to intercept their communications.
>  Upon decoding the communications, you discover that Vyander, the Enclave commander, is heading towards the Wasteland so that he can activated the Nexus there in order to open a portal that allows the Enclave to invade Acheron en masse. You pursue Vyander westward, and help to extricate Lord Halcyon’s forces which have become trapped between Typhon and the Enclave.
>  You first destroy the Xeno Mothership, preventing it from bombarding the area. With that threat taken care of for the moment you head towards the Nexus, where Typhon has surrounded Lord Halcyon’s line of defense. After destroying the Raider main guard, Typhon tells you that you haven’t successfully foiled his plans yet, and that he will use the Prometheus to destroy the Nexus…which will also destroy Acheron.
>  Fortunately, however, you defeat the remainder of Typhon’s forces before he can do so. Typhon then retreats to Kytos, the Raider homeland. For now, all the threats to the Empire have been eliminated.

**NEXUS CAMPAIGN**

> You follow Lord Halcyon as a full-on invasion of Kytos is launched, in order to capture Typhon and bring him to justice. The initial landing is at the Kor Encampment, a settlement of the Raiders. Katana tells everyone to avoid attacking the civilians, but Lord Halcyon overrules her, instead ordering you to eliminate the local militia and search the villages for weapons, since they are supporters of Typhon.
>  Although Typhon is getting away, Lord Halcyon orders you to destroy all the raider settlements. Katana objects as the civilians are not at war with the Empire, and the mission is to capture Typhon, not to kill innocent people. Lord Halcyon, however, insists that as long as the Raiders exist as a people the Empire will not be safe, and that they must be crushed. Unwilling to stand by while a genocide is carried out, you and Katana defect in order to protect the civilians from Lord Halcyon’s forces.
>  You contact Yurich, the leader of the local military. He is unwilling to trust you initially, but accepts that you are not enemies after you successfully defend the encampment from the Imperial forces. He tells you that not all of the Raiders support Typhon Vex, but that they allow him to remain in power due to his leadership skills and his vision for the future of the Raiders. Yurich himself, however, only wishes for the war to end. Since the only way Lord Halcyon will stand down is if Typhon is captured, Yurich tells you he is heading to the Blightlands in the north, and that he will assist you if will head to peace.
>  You head north into Sufuris, which has been overrun by the Bloodthirsty from the Blightlands. During your battles here, you discover that Typhon is searching for some other ancient power source after his previous attempts were foiled. You then head into the Odeus Mines as that is the only way to reach the Blightlands. In the mines however, you discover the Enclave has been carrying out a mining operation for Neocyte, a powerful energy source which powers the Enclave’s technology. In other words, they’re planning something.
>  You finally break out of the mines and reach the Blightlands, the original home of the Bloodthirsty. Here, you fight through the endless Bloodthirsty hordes as well as Halcyon’s Imperial forces. You then discover that there is in fact a second Nexus located here. Typhon intends to activate this Nexus in order to gain enough power to destroy the Empire, regardless of the risk it holds. The last time a Nexus was activated during the storyline of the original War Metal game, it completely destroyed the Asphodel region…which is now called the Wasteland. If the Nexus is successfully activated without destroying everything, however, it will be able to power the entire continent and allow Typhon’s power to match the Empire’s.
>  You finally catch up with Typhon, but it is too late. The countdown has already been activated, and the Nexus opens, engulfing Kytos in a firestorm and unleashing the power that will enable Typhon to destroy the Empire once and for all.

**BLIGHT CAMPAIGN**

> You and Katana wake up in Tartarus, a twisted dimension filled with Bloodthirsty creatures unlike any you have seen. The Nexus warped you here when it activated, but sent Yurich somewhere else. Due to the poisonous atmosphere your body is beginning to decay, which is attracting the Bloodthirsty to your position.
>  After defeating the Bloodthirsty, you encounter a group of Imperial soldiers led by Lucina. Katana comments on how this means Lord Halcyon is sending his own subordinates into almost certain death. Lucina then attacks you, believing you to be aiding Typhon. After defeating her forces, you manage to salvage the suits the Imperial soldiers were wearing, which protects you from the atmosphere.
>  You fight through some more huge swarms of Bloodthirsty, delving deeper into Tartarus. You find Typhon along with his loyal subordinate Barracus, who holds you off while Typhon continues searching for some way to unlock more power from Tartarus. This, combined with the Bloodthirsty which have developed entirely new abilities due to Tartarus’ influence, hinder you as you attempt to follow Typhon.
>  The Bloodthirsty begin to surround you forcing you to continue on. You then arrive in the Tartarus Breeding Pits, where you have another confrontation with Lucina’s forces. In the Breeding Pits, you begin detecting some strange energy emanating from the depths. This is revealed to be the Tartarus Core, which Typhon intends to absorb the power from. Right before you can head into the Core however, Lucina battles you for one final time.
>  Katana then asks Lucina why she is still following Halcyon’s orders when he has become just as bad as Typhon, and says that regardless of the respective sides they are on, that the first priority should be to stop Typhon. Lucina grudgingly agrees to a temporary truce with you, but is still unwilling to work with you. Therefore, you split into two groups to take out Typhon in a two-pronged attack. You manage to fight through the hordes of Bloodthirsty and reach Typhon, but Lucina is pinned down, and she tells you to do whatever it takes to stop Typhon.
>  Katana states that it’s odd the Bloodthirsty are ignoring Typhon since absorbing the core’s energy may destroy them all. They are, however, still attempting to stop you. You arrive at the core after defeating the last of the Bloodthirsty, where Typhon is being engulfed by the glow emitted from it. Katana orders everyone to attack at once in order to stop him, but Typhon says that you are, once again, too late. The light then engulfs him along with all of you, ending things on a cliffhanger.

**PURITY CAMPAIGN**

> You are roused by Katana, who says that you must stop Typhon, who has fused with the Tartarus Core and gained the powers of the Bloodthirsty. He now possesses the power to transform other creatures and machines into Bloodthirsty, and to make things worse this has now caused all the Tartarus Bloodthirsty to rally under him, defending him against your assaults. You then make a few more futile attempts to take down Typhon, to no avail. Suddenly, Yurich appears through a portal and bails you out.
>  Thanks to the portal, you are able to return to Acheron. Upon arrival, you are attacked by the Raider commander Cassandra who accuses Yurich of being a traitor, as he had gained her help by claiming that he was trying to rescue Typhon. After you repel her attack, Yurich explains that when he had arrived in Tartarus, he was unable to find you, but managed to find a portal back to Acheron. Due to Typhon’s shenanigans, the interdimensional boundary between Acheron and Tartarus has become dangerously unstable, and as a result the Blight has poured forth and covered Acheron, bringing with it the Tartarus Bloothirsty.
>  Yurich says that your current location is Triton Isle, the home of the Righteous faction who oppose the Bloodthirsty threat. He tells you that he must return to the Raiders before Cassandra can get to them and turn them against him, and departs. You are then greeted by Alaric, a member of the Righteous, who requests your help fighting the Bloodthirsty. Alaric says that although the Righteous are powerful, their power does not extend far past their home islands, and that the ritual must be completed first in order to truly turn the tide.
>  Katana inquires as to the nature of this ritual, and Alaric says that once the Pantheons have gained enough power, the Sentinel will be summoned to destroy the non-believers. In other words, the Righteous intend to wipe out the entire living population of Acheron. Katana says this is insane, but Alaric claims it is necessary to preserve the purity of the world and prevent Typhon’s victory. Unfortunately, Katana and you disagree, and thus you begin fighting against the Righteous as well.

**HOMEWORLD CAMPAIGN**

> You intercept a transmission from Halcyon about something he’s doing back in Empire territory (which is being overrun by the blight). When you arrive there, you fight a couple imperials but then Halcyon convinces you to join forces with one of his commanders, Emanuel, to try to take control of a nexus and try to stop the blight.
>  You head over to Vistik Island, where a nexus is, and meet up with some Righteous (you fight them at first, but then Emanuel tells you you’re on the same side). You fight your way through Bloodthirsty and Xenos to get to the Nexus, where you were told to await Halcyon’s orders. But Emanuel instead turns on you (on Halcyon’s orders) and you fight him. Oh yeah, and the Righteous also turn on you, in order to get revenge for your work during the Purity expansion.
>  So you head back to Asphodel, trying to get to Halcyon again, fighting through all five factions. Through Gaia you discover that Halcyon intends to activate the nexus in the wasteland to eradicate the blight there (killing everything else in the process). So your new objective becomes getting to the wasteland’s nexus and stopping said activation.
>  After again fighting through everyone, you manage to get to the nexus, but as always, you’re too late to stop it. Instead you seek shelter in a bunker. After defeating the Emanuel, who was in the bunker, you wait out the destruction and then go back to the surface. Halcyon claims he was successful, and the Blight is gone, but Katana states that it is already spreading back.

**PHOBOS CAMPAIGN**

> Months after Halcyon's bomb on the Nexus failed to destroy it, you find yourself with Katana, Yurich, and a Sovereign Imperial named Daedalus on an island named Artemis (on which the Xenos destroyed an Imperial base in the original War Metal). Katana gives some background about the time the passed between mission 144 and mission 145. 
>  Katana: "Months have passed since the Blight have taken over our planet. Food is scarce and the Bloodthirsty roam freely like they own everything."
>  Daedalus asks the player, Katana, and Yurich to accompany him on a suicide mission to board the Xeno space station in orbit around the planet with an abandoned Xeno transport on the island. The orbit of the station is such that it will eventually be immediately above the Nexus in the Wasteland, and its ion cannon can destroy. While the group makes its way to the transport through the bloodthirsty that made it to the island, they begin discussing Halcyon, and they learn from Daedalus that Halcyon is holed up in The Spire in Ashrock (the region where the player starts) with his last supporters. Daedalus also says he and the Sovereign Imperials defected from Halycyon and recognize the player as the earliest Sovereign Imperials. 
>  The player dispatches the group of Xenos that defend the transport and the raider group that attacks to prevent the group from leaving the ground. The Raiders mention a name: Lord Silus.
>  Then temporarily, the story of the sovereign Imperials stops and the player is put in control of a Righteous Vicar. A Righteous council is requesting the presence of you and Attalia, and are in a sanctuary on the other side of Valhalla. On the way to the sanctuary Attalia notes that the Bloodthirsty have become stronger, possibly due to the weakened Pantheons. The player then fights around Xenos, Raiders, and Bloodthirsty attacking the Sanctuary and rescues the Righteous Council.
>  The Vicar with Attalia escort the Council to Vistik Island, where the Nexus that cannot be targeted by the Phobos Station is located. You escort the Council to perform the ritual on the Nexus here and sucessfully defend them from Bloodthirsty, Raiders, and rogue Imperials. When the ritual is done, the Nexus there is destroyed, the Council members drop unconcious, and Attalia remarks that they are weakened but not dead.
>  The Imperial storyline continues here. You, Yurich, Katana, and Daedalus approach the station while a conversation about the aforementioned Lord Silus ensues. Silus, according to Yurich is a strong leader, and in a time such as this, Yurich says his people follow a strong leader such as Silus and that Silus promised to the raider people that the return of Typhon will bring glory to them all. After this explanation, the Xenos on the station attempt to contact the group's transport. Upon realizing that they are not Xeno, the station opens fire.
>  The transport is heavily damaged, but the group manages to crash land on the station. After taking care of the Xeno gate guards, Katana and Yurich head to the control room to revert power to the ion cannon, while Daedalus and the player will secure the cannon's controls. After fighting through Xeno and some of Silus's raiders under the command of Svetlana that proclaim that Yurich is a traitor, the player reaches the Cannon controls. Katana barely diverts the power in time while Yurich holds off Svetlana. 
>  After firing the cannon at the nexus in the Wasteland, Katana asks if the nexus is destroyed, but Daedalus says he is unsure, but will send a unit to assess the nexus after they land back on Acheron. Then, everyone realizes that the cannon depleted the energy reserves and the station is running on weak auxiliary power, and therefore the life support system will fail soon. After a while Daedalus disappears from the comm channel. Teiffa, another Sovereign Imperial appears. She talks about how Daedalus did not underestimate the player, and that she doesn't know about Daedalus's whereabouts either so everyone will have to wait until they get planetside before they can discover if everyone made it out of the station.

**PHOBOS AFTERMATH CAMPAIGN**

> More Xeno converge aroud the Ion Cannon controls and attempt to destroy the player, who had been separated from Daedalus, as revealed at the end of the last campaign. The player fights through them to move towards the docks where Xeno transports in good condition are located. Katana also starts heading towards the docks, although there is no message from Yurich. The Raider rear guard and remaining Xeno harass the player and Katana as both approach and board one of the remaining transports.
>  Almost everyone, it seems, makes it back to the surface alive. As soon as Katana and the player reach the surface, they are greeted by Teiffa, who says she spotted transports that might be Daedalus’s forces and that they will head towards that location. In addition they must also check on the status of the Nexus. The remainder of the Xeno from the station that comprise the few that managed to escape then attack the group and annihilate themselves.
>  The group then fights through Bloodthirsty stragglers in order to reach the spotted transports before realizing that the transports were raider. The Raiders then ambush the player to buy time to deploy their larger units. Daedalus, it turned out, landed between these advance Raiders and the main Raider force. You, Katana, Teiffa, and Daedalus then fight the main Raider force and win. You finally see the Nexus again, and confirm that it was in fact destroyed.

**AWAKENING CAMPAIGN**

> To be updated...

**TERMINUS CAMPAIGN**

> To be updated...

**OCCUPATION CAMPAIGN**

> Not released as of posting.

Comment: If you could cite where you got these sources, that would be great.  Anyways, great answer!

Comment: I found all of these scattered throughout Kongregate's Tyrant Forums.  I had some trouble finding the awakening and terminus campaigns, but if I have time I will summarize them myself.  Would you like me to include the side missions as well?

Comment: Hey, don't worry about it.  This perfectly addresses my question.  Thanks!